# Not able to inject a multi-binding with kotlin and dagger

Tags: kotlin, dagger-2

I have the following definitions:

```
@Module
class WeaverDataModule {
    // Provide the three pumps from providers
    // All of them still explicitly mark 'Pump' as their return type
    @Provides @IntoSet fun providesPump(thermosiphon: Thermosiphon) : Pump = thermosiphon
    @Provides @IntoSet fun providesAnotherPump(suctionBased: SuctionBased) : Pump = suctionBased
    @Provides @IntoSet fun providesGenericPump(genericPump: GenericPump) : Pump = genericPump
}

@Component(modules = [WeaverDataModule::class])
interface WeaverData {
    // Get the CoffeeMaker
    fun coffeeMaker(): CoffeeMaker
    // Get the list of pumps
    fun getPumps() : Set<Pump>
}

interface Pump

// The three pumps
class Thermosiphon @Inject constructor(val heater: Heater) : Pump
class SuctionBased @Inject constructor() : Pump
class GenericPump @Inject constructor() : Pump

// Some random heater
class Heater @Inject constructor()
```

In my code, when I do the following:

```
val cm = DaggerWeaverData.builder().build().getPumps()
```

I do get the three pumps as expected. However, when I'm trying to inject it into some other class:

```
class CoffeeMaker @Inject constructor(
    private val heater: Heater,
    private val pump: Set<Pump>
) {
    fun makeCoffee() =
        "Making coffee with heater ${heater::class.java} and using pumps" +
                " ${pump.map { it::class.java }.joinToString(",")}"
}
```

I get the following error:

```
e: .../WeaverData.java:7: error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] java.util.Set<? extends weaver.Pump> cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.                    
public abstract interface WeaverData {
                ^
      java.util.Set<? extends weaver.Pump> is injected at
          weaver.CoffeeMaker(…, pump)
      weaver.CoffeeMaker is provided at
          weaver.WeaverData.coffeeMaker()
```

I've tried injecting `Collection<Pump>` also, but I still get a similar error. In the [dagger docs on multibinding](https://google.github.io/dagger/multibindings), the example (in Java) shows the following:

```
class Bar {
  @Inject Bar(Set<String> strings) {
    assert strings.contains("ABC");
    assert strings.contains("DEF");
    assert strings.contains("GHI");
  }
}
```

which is exactly what I'm doing. And for constructor-based injection, it is working just fine in Kotlin, because the following compiles and runs as expected:

```
class CoffeeMaker @Inject constructor(
    private val heater: Heater
) {
    fun makeCoffee() =
        "Making coffee with heater ${heater::class.java}"
}
```

So I'm kind of at a loss on how do I get this multibinding to work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So turns out what you need to do is:

```
class CoffeeMaker @Inject constructor(
    private val heater: Heater,
    private val pumps: Set<@JvmSuppressWildcards Pump>
) {
    fun makeCoffee() =
        "Making coffee with heater ${heater::class.java} with pumps ${pumps.map { it::class.java }.joinToString(",")}"
}
```

This is because `Set` is defined in Kotlin as `Set<out E>` which translates into Java as `Set<? extends Pump>`. From a type-theory perspective, `Set<? extends Pump>` is different from `Set<Pump>` and hence Dagger (probably) refuses to see `Set<Pump>` as an injectable for `Set<? extends Pump>`, which is fair and the right behavior.

The problem we have is that for any of these collections, since they are immutable by default, a declaration of type `Set<X>` will translate to `Set<? extends X>`, as an immutable collection only has references to the resolved type on returns and is hence covariant. To verify this theory, the following also works:

```
class CoffeeMaker @Inject constructor(
    private val heater: Heater,
    private val pumps: MutableSet<Pump>
) {
    fun makeCoffee() =
        "Making coffee with heater ${heater::class.java} with pumps ${pumps.map { it::class.java }.joinToString(",")}"
}
```

Note the use of `MutableSet`, which is defined as `MutableSet<E> : Set<E> ...`. This is probably not something one should use because I doubt that this set is actually mutable. So what we do need is for the kotlin compiler to treat `Set<out E>` as `Set<E>` (the assignabiliy is valid in this case, just not the other way around). So do so, we use the `@JvmSuppressWildcards` annotation. I hope this helps somebody else facing similar issues.

Comment: I'd been using `MutableSet<T>` for a while with dagger as a workaround, and was never happy with this, I thought I'd try to rectify this obvious flaw.  Just to note that `@JvmSuppressWildcards` has to be included on all places `Set<T>` is used - from the injectable class, injected class and especially when using `@Binds`.  Also if you have a lot of injected arguments like this you can propagate the `@JvmSuppressWildcards` to the class and include only once.