# Dagger 2 is throwing compiling error when coded with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Dagger 2 is not able to create the subcomponent object when coded with kotlin.The same code is running fine when i am coding in java

```
// MainActivityComponent:
@Subcomponent
interface MainActivityComponent : AndroidInjector<MainActivity> {
    @Subcomponent.Builder
    abstract class Builder : AndroidInjector.Builder<MainActivity>() {

    }
}

ActivityBindingModule:
@Module(subcomponents = [MainActivityComponent::class])
abstract class ActivityBindingModule {

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ActivityKey(MainActivity::class)
    abstract fun getActivityInjectors(buider: MainActivityComponent.Builder): AndroidInjector.Factory<out Activity>
}
```

ActivityInjector:

```
class ActivityInjector @Inject constructor(val activityInjectors: Map<Class<out Activity>, Provider<AndroidInjector.Factory<out Activity>>>) {
    val cache = HashMap<String, AndroidInjector<out Activity>>()

    fun inject(activity: Activity) {
        if (activity !is BaseActivity) {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("activity must extend Base")
        }
        val instanceId = (activity as BaseActivity).getInstanceId()
        if (cache.containsKey(instanceId)) {
            val androidInjector = cache.get(instanceId) as AndroidInjector<Activity>
            androidInjector.inject(activity)
        } else {
            val androidInjectorFactory =
                activityInjectors.get(activity::class.java)?.get() as AndroidInjector.Factory<Activity>
            val androidInjector = androidInjectorFactory.create(activity)
            cache.put(instanceId, androidInjector)
            androidInjector.inject(activity)
        }
    }

    companion object {
        fun get(context: Context): ActivityInjector {
            return (context.applicationContext as MyApplication).getActivityInjectors()
        }
    }
}
```

---

MyApplication:

```
   class MyApplication : Application() {
             @Inject
             lateinit var activityInjector: ActivityInjector

            lateinit var applicationComponent: ApplicationComponent

            override fun onCreate() {
                super.onCreate()
                applicationComponent = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder().applicaitonModule(ApplicaitonModule(this)).build()
                applicationComponent.inject(this)


            }
            fun getActivityInjectors(): ActivityInjector {
                return activityInjector
            }
        }
```

Error:

> Expected:It should compile successfully and provide the proper
>   dependencies
>       Actual:: error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] java.util.Map,?
>   extends javax.inject.Provider>> cannot be provided without an
>   @Provides-annotated method.

Comment: Hi Tasmir,I couldn't able to understand what edit you suggested Can you please brief a little

Comment: I guess this should solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55420107/11342519

Comment: Hey @jsamol thanks a lot for taking out the time.I resolved the issue atlast.It seems the issue was with the field injection.I changed that into constructor injection and it started working.